# How to convert unity filepath code that works on pc so that in works for android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am calling a function which takes a screenshot within the game but this works only on pc since the filepath on android cant be accessed with the way i wrote the code

What should i change ?

```
 public void TakeScreenshot()
    {
        string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Assets/Screenshots/";        
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Path.Combine(filePath, "Level-Screenshot.png"));      
    }
```

I tried using  Application.dataPath but i dont know how to exactly call it

Answer (score 0):

So, when it comes to saving files on Android devices, the file paths are different than on PC. The Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() function is not going to work on Android.

Instead, like you mentioned, you can use the Application.dataPath to get the path to the persistent data directory on the Android device This directory is where you can store and access files on the device. Here is how you would use it in your code:

```
public void TakeScreenshot()
{
    string fileName = "Level-Screenshot.png";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Screenshots");
    if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
    }
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName));
}
```

This code creates a directory called "Screenshots" in the persistent data directory of the device, and saves the screenshot with the specified filename in that directory.

Let me know if you have any questions, or if it doesn't work!